# Trying to fix multiple category drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, content-management-system

I'm having some problems trying to fix my category drop down on the website i'm developing. Basically one drop down filters has "Sort by Location" and the second one is "Sort by Price" The first one is working correctly which is "Sort by Location" but the second one doesn't. It is loading all the post and not filtering properly.

Here is the link -

http://digitalspin.ph/federalland/?page_id=23

Here is my code

**HTML-**

```
<div class="filter_container">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args_cat1 ); ?> 
</div>

<div class="filter_container">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args_cat2 ); ?> 
</div>
```

**JS-**

```
<!--DROPDOWN SORT CATEGORY 1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat1");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>


<!--DROPDOWN SORT CATEGORY 2-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat2");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

**Functions.php**

```
//LOCATION FILTER

$args_cat2 = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '1,2,3,4,32,33,34,35,36,37',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat2',
'id'                 => 'cat2',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
'walker'             => ''
);

//PRICE FILTER

$args_cat1 = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '1,2,3,4,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat1',
'id'                 => 'cat1',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
'walker'             => ''
);
```

Here is a javascript error from firebug-

```
TypeError: dropdown is null
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
```

Whenever i pick a category in "Sort by Price" it display all the post from "Sort by Location" which is category ID 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you think your 2 javascripts are executed in different contexts, they are not. They are executed in the same context so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat1");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat2");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

Would produce the exact same result. You need to change the names of some of your variables and functions so they dont collide or do something like:

```
document.getElementById("cat1").onChange = function(){
    if ( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}

document.getElementById("cat2").onChange = function(){
    if ( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
```

Or maybe even better

```
var catChanger = function(){
    if ( this.options[this.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/?cat="+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}

document.getElementById("cat1").onChange = catChanger;    
document.getElementById("cat2").onChange = catChanger;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. I got it working thanks to your advice. Will keep this in mind